# How does SQL multiple table joining condition table reference work?

Tags: sql, join

I'm learning sql 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner2 and the condition clause of the second join bugs me:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Shippers.ShipperName
FROM ((Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
INNER JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID);
```

how does `Orders.ShipperID` work?

I think `Orders` here should be a reference to the '**intermediate**' table which is the result of the first `join` operation? Are operand table names preserved behind the scene? (my guessing)

Thanks!

Comment: We can't answer this without seeing your data, but yes, I might expect the join to shippers happening between customers and shippers, not what we see above.  Maybe the schema requires this though.

Comment: Thanks Tim you can check the data by clicking the table names on the right side of the page by my provided link.

Comment: There is no "result of the first join operation" - SQL uses all tables, participating in join and syntactically you can use all tables (aliases), preceding current one. (You can omit parens in your query, this doesn't change anything.) Thereby Orders.ShipperID is perfectly legal and it means ShipperID field from Orders table. For me such link makes sense too - in many systems order links to both customer and shipper, which themselves are usually not related.

Comment: Thanks Arvo, just wonder that is multiple join just cross product of all these tables? And then query can be made according to specific condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All tables and their joins are evaluated as a single expression. There is no "intermediate" table in your query.

The example in your question might be confusing because of the useless parentheses around the join expression.

If written without the useless parentheses, this might be clearer:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Shippers.ShipperName
FROM Orders 
  JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
  JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID;
```

So the table `orders` is simply joined to `customers` through the `customerid` and to the `shippers` table through the `shipperid` column.

This is a good example why useless parentheses very often do **not** improve readability.